# The greatest number among 10 such positive integers which add up to 101, such that none of them are greater than the twice of any of the numbers.

Tags: linear-algebra

I came across this very interesting question today. So is it about just breaking 101 into several numbers and see what matches the condition or is there a special way to do it?

Edit: Repetition is not allowed

Comment: I think this need a bit of clarification. If you look at
$$
10+10+10+10+10+10+10+10+10+11 = 101
$$
and 
$$
9+10+10+10+10+10+10+10+10+12 = 101
$$
The first one has largest value 11 and the latter has largest value 12 ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need 10 distinct positive integers such that

(i) their sum is 101

(ii) none of them is greater than twice of any number, which actually means that the greatest of them should be less than or equal to twice of the smallest number.

So let's say we arrange these 10 positive numbers in ascending order whose sum is 101. Let $a$ be the smallest number among them.

Case 1: $a\geq9$

The least possible sum with $a$ as the smallest number would be $9+10+11+12+13+14+15+16+17+18>101$ since repetition is not allowed.

Hypothesis (i) fails

Case 2: $a<9$

We can't find $10$ distinct positive integers $\in [a,2a]$ where $a\leq8$ is a positive integer.

Hypothesis (ii) fails

Conclusion: Such $10$ positive integers meeting both hypotheses (i) and (ii) don't exist.

Comment: makes sense... so the question is wrong